# Convert BERT model for Named Entity Recognition to ONNX. Input sequence length

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, onnx

I have exported my BERT model based on the following:
[Microsoft ONNX export](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-inference-examples/blob/main/python/azureml/export.py)

Assuming that it is saved as `model.onnx`

Shall I expect that my input sequence should always be truncated to the `max_len` dimension(512)? Or is there a way to handle dynamic inputs?

Further, is there a way to pack model and tokenizer to run inference in a pipeline? I saw that current huggingface libraries do not support loading ONNX models for NER task.